# Make button show AND hide navigation on website?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to hide and show the nav bar with the same button. I copied some code snippets around the interwebs and managed to oben the navigation with a custom animated button but there is stil a dedicated close button. how do i map the close function to the same button that opens the nav

thank you

PS: if you can tell me what to change so the navigation comes from the right not the left id be very gratefull

```js
/*bar animation bar to cross*/
function myFunction(x) {
  x.classList.toggle("change");
}
/* Set the width of the side navigation to 250px */
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "500px";
}

/* Set the width of the side navigation to 0 */
function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
}
```

```css
/* Header */


/* Style the header with a grey background and some padding */

.header {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  padding-top: 40px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}


/* Style the header links */

.header a {
  float: left;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 12px;
  padding-right: 12px;
  padding-left: 12px;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: lato;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 25px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.menu_bar_icon {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.bar1,
.bar2,
.bar3 {
  width: 20px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #000000;
  margin: 4px 0;
  transition: 0.4s;
}


/* Rotate first bar */

.change .bar1 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-4px, 3px);
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-4px, 3px);
}


/* Fade out the second bar */

.change .bar2 {
  opacity: 0;
}


/* Rotate last bar */

.change .bar3 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-5px, -4px);
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-5px, -4px);
}


/* The side navigation menu */

.sidenav {
  height: 90px;
  /* 100% Full-height */
  width: 0;
  /* 0 width - change this with JavaScript */
  position: fixed;
  /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1;
  /* Stay on top */
  top: 0;
  /* Stay at the top */
  left: 70%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  /* Disable horizontal scroll */
  padding-top: 50px;
  /* Place content 60px from the top */
  transition: 0.5s;
  /* 0.5 second transition effect to slide in the sidenav */
}


/* The navigation menu links */

.sidenav a {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #000000;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}


/* When you mouse over the navigation links, change their color */

.sidenav a:hover {
  color: #E20105;
}


/* Position and style the close button (top right corner) */

.sidenav .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}


/* Style page content - use this if you want to push the page content to the right when you open the side navigation */

#main {
  transition: margin-left .5s;
  padding: 20px;
}


/* On smaller screens, where height is less than 450px, change the style of the sidenav (less padding and a smaller font size) */

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {
    padding-top: 15px;
  }
  .sidenav a {
    font-size: 18px;
  }
}


/* Style the logo link (notice that we set the same value of line-height and font-size to prevent the header to increase when the font gets bigger */

.header a.logo {
  font-size: 130px;
  font-weight: bold;
}


/* Change the background color on mouse-over */

.header a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}


/* Style the active/current link*/

.header a.active {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  color: white;
}


/* Float the link section to the right */

.header-right {
  float: right;
}


/* Add media queries for responsiveness - when the screen is 500px wide or less, stack the links on top of each other */

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .header a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
  .header-right {
    float: none;
  }
}

#container {
  width: 100%;
  /* Your width */
  height: 100%;
  /* Your height */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  /* This will center container with items horizontally */
  align-items: center;
  /* This will center container with items vertically */
  /*   outline: 5px dashed yellow;
*/
}
```

```html
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<div class="header">
  <a href="#default" class="logo">Kunden;</a>
  <div class="header-right">
    <div class="menu_bar_icon" onclick="myFunction(this), openNav()">
      <div class="bar1"></div>
      <div class="bar2"></div>
      <div class="bar3"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
      <a href="#">About</a>
      <a href="#">Services</a>
      <a href="#">Clients</a>
      <a href="#">Contact</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use [`.classList.toggle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) to toggle between css classes, notice that I removed the close function and open function, and moved the width to CSS class.

```css
/*html, body {
    max-width: 100%;
 max-height: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
 overflow-y: hidden;
 
}
#fullbodybg{
    position: absolute;
    width: 170%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: visible;
    background: linear-gradient(
 110deg,
 #ffffff 50%,
 #000000 50%);
    outline: 5px dashed blue;
}*/

/* Header */

/* Style the header with a grey background and some padding */
.header {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    padding-top: 40px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

/* Style the header links */
.header a {
    float: left;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 12px;
    padding-right: 12px;
    padding-left: 12px;
    padding-bottom: 12px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: lato;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 25px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
.menu_bar_icon {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.bar1, .bar2, .bar3 {
    width: 20px;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: #000000;
    margin: 4px 0;
    transition: 0.4s;
}
/* Rotate first bar */
.change .bar1 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-4px, 3px) ;
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-4px, 3px) ;
}

/* Fade out the second bar */
.change .bar2 {
  opacity: 0;
}

/* Rotate last bar */
.change .bar3 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-5px, -4px) ;
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-5px, -4px) ;
}
/* The side navigation menu */
.sidenav {
  height: 90px;
  width: 352px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 70%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding-top: 50px;
  transition: 0.5s;
  width: 500px;
  right: -540px;
  left: auto;
}
/* The navigation menu links */
.sidenav a {
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #000000;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

/* When you mouse over the navigation links, change their color */
.sidenav a:hover {
    color: #E20105;
}

/* Position and style the close button (top right corner) */
.sidenav .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

/* Style page content - use this if you want to push the page content to the right when you open the side navigation */
#main {
  transition: margin-left .5s;
  padding: 20px;
}

/* On smaller screens, where height is less than 450px, change the style of the sidenav (less padding and a smaller font size) */
@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
  .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
}
/* Style the logo link (notice that we set the same value of line-height and font-size to prevent the header to increase when the font gets bigger */
.header a.logo {
  font-size: 130px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

/* Change the background color on mouse-over */
.header a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

/* Style the active/current link*/
.header a.active {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  color: white;
}

/* Float the link section to the right */
.header-right {
  float: right;
}

/* Add media queries for responsiveness - when the screen is 500px wide or less, stack the links on top of each other */
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .header a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
  .header-right {
    float: none;
  }
}
#container{
   width: 100%;/* Your width */
   height: 100%;/* Your height */
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center; /* This will center container with items horizontally */
   align-items: center; /* This will center container with items vertically */
/*   outline: 5px dashed yellow;
*/
}



#mySidenav.open {
  right: 0;
  z-index: 0;
  left: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>HFFoto - Portfolio</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" id="applicationStylesheet" href="portfolio_kunden.css"/>
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<style type="text/css">
</style>
 
<script>


/*bar animation bar to cross*/
function myFunction(x) {
  x.classList.toggle("change");
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").classList.toggle('open');
}


</script>
 
</head>
 
<body>
<div class="header">
    <a href="#default" class="logo">Kunden;</a>
  <div class="header-right">
      <div class="menu_bar_icon" onclick="myFunction(this)">
     <div class="bar1"></div>
     <div class="bar2"></div>
     <div class="bar3"></div>
  </div> 
    <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
     
     <a href="#">About</a>
    <a href="#">Services</a>
     <a href="#">Clients</a>
     <a href="#">Contact</a>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you so much this works. dont know how but it does :D do you know i can make the navigation com in from the right not the left?:)

Comment: Glad to help, let me check if I can get it working.

Comment: I updated my answer please check and consider [accepting answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if you find my answer useful :) also note that I changed the attribute we manipulate to left, and right, also I didn't look into having it responsive.

Answer (score 1):

This could work, but I do not know what you want to click after opening the menu

```
window.addEventListener("load",function() {
  document.querySelector(".menu_bar_icon").addEventListener("click",function() {
    this.classList.toggle("change");
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = this.classList.contains("change") ? "500px" : 0;
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function navToggle() {
  var ele = document.getElementById("mySidenav");
  if (ele.classList.contains("isVisible")) {
    ele.classList.remove("isVisible");
    ele.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    ele.classList.add("isVisible");
    ele.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="menu_bar_icon" onclick="navToggle()">
      Click Me!
      <div class="bar1"></div>
      <div class="bar2"></div>
      <div class="bar3"></div>
</div>

<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav isVisible">
      <a href="#">About</a>
      <a href="#">Services</a>
      <a href="#">Clients</a>
      <a href="#">Contact</a>
</div>
```

```
<div class="menu_bar_icon" onclick="navToggle()">
      Click Me!
      <div class="bar1"></div>
      <div class="bar2"></div>
      <div class="bar3"></div>
</div>

<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav isVisible">
      <a href="#">About</a>
      <a href="#">Services</a>
      <a href="#">Clients</a>
      <a href="#">Contact</a>
</div>

function navToggle() {
  var ele = document.getElementById("mySidenav");
  if (ele.classList.contains("isVisible")) {
    ele.classList.remove("isVisible");
    ele.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    ele.classList.add("isVisible");
    ele.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

Comment: sadly cant get this to worked, looked so simple :) when pressing the button just nothing happens

Comment: @awesome_o Sorry, I had a syntax error in there.   I'll update my answer.   Correct code can also be found here ... https://jsfiddle.net/b0w132nt/

Comment: @awesome_o updated answer with working code + snippet